# Load .sql file to a DataSet or DataTable with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, file, datatable

Is it possible to load a `.sql` file into a `DataSet` or `DataTable` without executing it on a SQL Server database and then read the values from the database?

I know the way to load the `.sql` file into SQL Server and then read out the values, but is there a way to skip this because I don't have the option to create a SQL Server on the PC at the moment.

The `.sql` file has a `CREATE TABLE` statement and a `INSERT INTO` query with some data

Greetz.

Comment: Well, you *could* try to parse the SQL contained in that file and *extract* the data from it ..... not a very good and productive idea, in my opinion... either get that data in a `.csv` or `.xml` instead (which you can easily load into a `DataTable`), or then execute the `.sql` against your database....

Comment: its an .sql file. And the way to search in the file for the values and read them is bad... It dont can be the only way to create a database, execute the sql to the database and load the database in c#... ;D

Answer (score 1):

In-Memory SQSQLite or SQL Server CE maybe? Depends on whats in your SQL file, and if there are any SQL Server specific statements.

In that case it pretty much boils down to

1. In-memory database (would be my preferred option)
2. Parsing the file directly using a custom adapter. Maybe its a good idea for you to start an open source project. And once you come across hiccups to ask for help ;-)

Comment: So there is no way other?

Comment: What other way are you looking for? As mentioned by @marc_s you could try to parse the SQL file.

Comment: I dont have the option to create a sql datebase on the working pc at the moment, so i'm searching for a way to execute the .sql file directly to a DataTable or DataSet object or something else.

Comment: What about another SQL database on another PC / Server which you have dbo permissions on?